# Nest 29840 - ExceptionsHandler Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, circular-dependency

NextJS backend issue while dealing with http post, It throws converting circular structure to JSON error.

Here is the code stack trace which details issue

```
[Nest] 29840   - 01/04/2021, 2:46:31 PM   ExceptionsHandler Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle +199712ms
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json \node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ExpressAdapter.reply node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:24:57)    
    at RouterResponseController.apply node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-response-controller.js:13:36)
    at \node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:173:48
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:47:13
    at async \node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Answer (score 4):

It took some time to figure out solution however this issue can be resolved by adding below code

this.http.post(`https://api-enpont`,body, headerData).pipe( map(response => response.data));

Do not forget to import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Thank you for this. The nest.js docs on how to use axios are not detailed enough.